# github action azure/login@v1 not working on self hosted git runner?

Tags: github, github-actions, azure-cli

Anyone familiar with this issue? The example from https://github.com/Azure/cli does not work on self-hosted github runner it seems as `az is missing`

gitaction.yml

```
name: auzure-deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux]
    steps:
    - uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    - uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.0.72
        inlineScript: |
          az account list
```

**error**

```
Runner group name: 'Default'
Machine name: '98de1add3979'
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
Prepare workflow directory
Prepare all required actions
Getting action download info
Download action repository 'azure/login@v1'
Download action repository 'azure/CLI@v1'
0s
Run azure/login@v1
Error: Az CLI Login failed. Please check the credentials. For more information refer https://aka.ms/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows
Error: Error: Unable to locate executable file: az. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
```

I hacked a workaround to not have to use loging@v1 but its not elegant, as they secrets are printed to the git log prompt:

```
name: auzure-deployment
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  buildandpush:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux]
    env: 
      credentials: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
      AZURE_CLIENT_ID: ${{ fromJSON(secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS)['clientId'] }}
      AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ fromJSON(secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS)['clientSecret'] }}
      AZURE_TENANT_ID: ${{ fromJSON(secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS)['tenantId'] }}
    - uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.0.72
        inlineScript: |
          az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID
          az account list
```

Comment: can you try replacing "az" with "/usr/bin/az"? Also try removing all of the "inlineScript" (az login and az account list) and replace with "/usr/bin/az --version" just to check if it can find it at all.

Answer (score 3):

There's now an open issue to install the cli in the login action if it doesn't exist: https://github.com/Azure/login/issues/154

The work around on self hosted runners is to install the cli before the login action using another action like this https://github.com/elstudio/action-install-azure-cli

or to not be dependent on someone elses action, run the commands directly from the script in the above repo.

```
      - name: Install Azure cli
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg
          curl -sL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg > /dev/null
          AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)
          echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install azure-cli
      - uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
      - uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          azcliversion: 2.0.72
          inlineScript: |
            az account list
```