# AZ CLI Issue - Github Actions Self hosted runner

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-cli, building-github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I get the error shown in screenshot below while trying to fetch Azure key vault secrets using Azure CLI from github actions. The error says `Please run 'az login' to setup account.`

As one can see, the AZ login was successful in the previous step. Based on the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67426632/github-action-azure-loginv1-not-working-on-self-hosted-git-runner), I have installed Azure CLI - eventhough the output says Azure CLI is already up to date in the self hosted runner.

What can be done to overcome this issue?

yml snippet

```
- name: Install Azure CLI
    run: |
      sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg
      curl -sL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor | 
      sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg > /dev/null
      AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)
      echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO 
      main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install azure-cli
      
  - name: Login to Azure
    uses: azure/login@v1
    with:
       client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
       tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
       subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
  - uses: azure/CLI@v1
    with: 
      inlineScript: |
        value1=$(az keyvault secret show --name $AZURE_SECRET_NAME --vault-name $AZURE_KEYVAULT_NAME --query value -o tsv)
        echo $value1
        value2=$(az keyvault secret show --name $AZURE_SECRET_NAME --vault-name $AZURE_KEYVAULT_NAME --query value)
        echo $value2
        #echo "::add-mask::$value"
        #printf "%s\n" $value >> GITHUB_OUTPUT
        echo "${value2//\"}" >> GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

[image]

Comment: Try using later versions of the Login and Cli actions.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the below Github workflow and got the Key vault secrets successfully after successful login by installing Azure CLI, Refer below:-

**My github workflow:-**

My complete github workflow [**Link**](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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)

Referred Install Azure CLI commands from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt)
and az key vault secret show command from [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-show)

```yaml
name: Azure Key Vault Secrets

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install Azure CLI
      run: |
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg
        sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
        curl -sLS https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc |
            gpg --dearmor |
            sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/microsoft.gpg > /dev/null
        sudo chmod go+r /etc/apt/keyrings/microsoft.gpg
        AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)
        echo "deb [arch=`dpkg --print-architecture` signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ $AZ_REPO main" |
        sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install azure-cli

    - name: Login to Azure
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

    - name: Authenticate Azure CLI
      run: az login

    - uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with: 
        inlineScript: |
          value1=$(az keyvault secret show --name keyvaultsecret --vault-name siliconkeyvault12 --query value -o tsv)
          echo $value1
          value2=$(az keyvault secret show --name keyvaultsecret --vault-name siliconkeyvault12 --query value)
          echo $value2
          #echo "::add-mask::$value"
          #printf "%s\n" $value >> GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "${value2//\"}" >> GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

In Authenticate Azure CLI step it asked me to authenticate with the URL which I authenticated with my Azure account having proper role assigned on Key vault to access secret refer below:-

[image]

[image]

**Key vault secret value got printed successfully like below:-**

[image]

**Portal:-**

***Key vault IAM to my user account:-***

[image]

***Key vault Secret:-***

[image]

My Access policy is set to IAM in my Key vault.